# Can't initialize OCI. Error -1. Toad for Oracle 10 and Oracle 10g

Tags: oracle10g, toad

I am trying to connect Oracle 10g database server from my client PC using toad 10 Commercial. I have Oracle 10g installed in my PC. When I try to connect, it gives error Can't initialize OCI.Error -1 . 
So far I am able to perform tnsping to the oracle server. I have all the settings working in my tnsnames.ora.
Any suggestions are highly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found the solution myself. The problem was with windows 7 permission issue.
I opened Toad with run as administrator , privilege and the problem get solved.

Answer (score 2):

Taken from https://support.quest.com/SolutionDetail.aspx?id=SOL61710

RESOLUTION 1:
Right-click the Toad for Oracle shortcut and select "Run as Administrator" to avoid the error.

RESOLUTION 2:
Right-click the Toad for Oracle shortcut | Properties | Compatibility Tab | check mark "Run this program in compatibility mode for" | choose "Windows XP Service Pack 3" from the drop-down list.

RESOLUTION 3:
Right-click My Computer | Properties | Advanced tab | Environment Variables | under ‘System Variables’ (lower part) | check if you have an entry for ORACLE_HOME. If yes, rename it to ORACLE_HOME_OLD, and then re-test the issue.

RESOLUTION 4:
Upgrade your Oracle client to a version that is 10.2.0.4 or later.

Answer (score 0):

I have another resolution. I had this issue ater setting NLS_LANG environment variable to  LATIN AMERICAN SPANISH.
When rebooting windows7, TOAD would not start showing error Can't initialize OCI. Error -1
I had to delete NLS_LANG / NLS_LANGUAGE environment variable.
Now i have to set NLS_LANGUAGE executing ALTER SESSION while logged in TOAD.
No OCI error anymore.

Hope it halps.

Answer (score 0):

Kindly follow up the below steps to solve the (Can't initialize OCI. Error -1)title issue.

1. go to enviroment variable
2. remove all variable path in user variable.
3. Also check the permission.

Thanks
Anandaraj